# Class based views and 'raise NotImplementedError'

Tags: python, django, exception

I had a function-based code looking like this:

```
def foo(request):
  raise NotImplementedError()
```

How is this supposed to use in class-based views?

```
class FooView(View):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

**EDIT > QUESTION:** Question is about syntax. FooView is not an abstract class, it is implemented class. When I tried to use `return raise NotImplementedError()` - it gave me an error. Should I put `NotImplementedError` inside `get()` or some other function?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're going for here.  Perhaps if you could describe the _behavior_ that you're looking for we could understand the question better...

Comment: The idea is that FooView is not implemented yet, but it has to be defined for future development. So FooView has to be empty class that raises NotImplementedError(), just for convenience.

Comment: So it's supposed to be an abstract base class?

Comment: Nope, supposed to be implemented class. Edited the question itself, please, check it. I guess I was not specific enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you do it correctly, call `raise NotImplementedError()` inside the functions that are not implemented and it will get raised every time these functions get called:

```
>>> class NotImplementedError(Exception):
...     pass
... 
>>> class FooView(object):
...     def get(self):
...         raise NotImplementedError()
... 
>>> v = FooView()
>>> v.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in get
__main__.NotImplementedError
```

You can raise the exception anywhere you deem it useful, e.g. in the constructor to indicate that the whole class is not implemented:

```
>>> class FooView(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         raise NotImplementedError()
... 
>>> v = FooView()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
__main__.NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for. I haven't found this on web.